# Can you call multiple stored procedures as part of a transaction rollback c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored proc that creates a record.

Can i use a SqlTransaction object to call the create multiple times and rollback all of the inserts if any fail?

Comment: great, have you tried it?

Comment: **Yes.** That's the **very definition** of a transaction - either everything works - or everything is rolled back.

Comment: yes you can rollback function is for that purpose only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the stored procedure doesn't commit itself: Yes, you can do that.

It's kind of the reason for having transactions in the first place.

Comment: I think this is the problem i was having. I was committing the transaction in the proc as well as in c# code.

Comment: you can have  a try and catch block and call your commit function in try block if any exception occurs you can call the rollback function in catch block

Comment: How many hops to the database would this do? One or one for each stored proc?

Comment: @user1168234: Only one: `TRANSACTION ROLLBACK` (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just execute the command multiple times in the transaction and add a `try/catch` block for the commit/rollback:

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

try {
      // Execute Stored Procedure n times here.
      transaction.Commit();
} catch(SQLException e) {
     transaction.Rollback();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx

For best practice you may want to wrap the `.Rollback` in a try/catch just in case the rollback fails.

Comment: How many hops to the database would this do? One or one for each stored proc?